# Preciso de código que me permita dar update a posts php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Basicamente, preciso fazer código que me possibilite atualizar (editar) postagens que pertençam ao mesmo ID do Post.ID.
Exemplo :
Login: okok@gmail.com
Passe: $ # $ # $
Login sucedido !!
Assim que alguém faz o login, é redirecionado para o meu índice, onde é mostrado todas as postagens feitas, junto com a hora em que foram criadas, a hora em que foram atualizadas e o nome da pessoa que postou, como se pode ver na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No canto superior direito, devo codificar um botão "Atualizar", desde que a postagem tenha sido feita por "mim", pelo usuário em causa.
Fiz algum código, mas nem o botão aparece.

```
  {foreach item=post from=$posts}
  <div class="boxed">
    <div class="container p-1 my-1" style="text-align:center;">
      {if $post.user_id == $id_value}
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:right;">
          <a href="blog.php?micropost_id={$post.post_id}"
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">update blog</button>
          </a>
        </div>
      {/if}
      <h4 style="color:purple">{$post.name}</h4>
      <h5 style="color:black">{$post.content}</h5>
      <p style="color:white">
      <div style="color:purple"class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:right;">updated: {$post.updated_at}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">created: {$post.created_at}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
  {/foreach}
</body>
</html>
```

Este código faz parte do meu índice, onde consigo mostrar todas as postagens já feitas, e como podem ver, estou a tentar fazer um botão, mas ele não aparece mais.

Answer (score -4):

​module​.​exports​ ​=​ ​{
​  ​roots​: ​[​'/src/'​,​ ​'/test/'​]​,
​  ​transform​: ​{
​    ​'^.+\.tsx?$'​: ​'ts-jest'​,
​  ​}​,
​  ​testMatch​: ​[​'**/integration/**/*-test.ts{,x}'​]​,
​  ​moduleFileExtensions​: ​[​'ts'​,​ ​'tsx'​,​ ​'js'​,​ ​'jsx'​,​ ​'json'​,​ ​'node'​]​,
​  ​setupFilesAfterEnv​: ​[​'/test/setup-test-framework.ts'​]​,
​  ​reporters​: ​[​'default'​,​ ​'../script/jest-actions-reporter.js'​]​,
​  ​globals​: ​{
​    ​'ts-jest'​: ​{

Comment: Não entendi....

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).